# Orthogonal functions on the circle with constraints

Tags: inner-products, orthonormal

I have a curious question that may be interesting to some.

Consider **real**-valued continuous functions on the circle $f_1(x),f_2(x),f_3(x)$ (so they are periodic in $x \mapsto x+2\pi$).

They have the following properties:

1. $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dx}{2\pi} f_i(x) = 0$
2. $ \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dx}{2\pi} f_i(x) f_j(x) = \frac{1}{3} \delta_{ij}$
3. $f_1(x)^2 +f_2(x)^2 + f_3(x)^2 = 1$ for all $x$.

Considered as square-summable vectors on the circle, the first two conditions mean that $f_i(x)$ are orthogonal to the constant function $1$, and they are mutually orthogonal, each with norm $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$. There are infinitely many functions that satisfy properties 1 and 2.

But is there a solution now also requiring property 3 to hold?

If yes, what is an example of such a set of functions? (Or more generically, how to construct them in general?)
If no, how do we rule them out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Partial Answer:**

Observe that:
$$(f_1+f_2+f_3)^2 = f_1^2+f_2^2+f_3^2+2f_1f_2+2f_1f_3+2f_2f_3$$
Therefore:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} (f_1+f_2+f_3)^2 \ dx = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f_1^2+f_2^2+f_3^2 \ dx = 1$$

Since each $f_i$ is continuous on a compact interval $[0,2\pi]$, they are all uniformly bounded by some constant $M > 0$. In particular:
$$-M \leq f_i \leq M$$
It follows that:
$$-3M \leq f_1+f_2+f_3 \leq 3M$$

If we include the additional assumption that $f_1+f_2+f_3 \geq 0$, then the following holds:
$$-3M(f_1+f_2+f_3) \leq (f_1+f_2+f_3)^2 \leq 3M(f_1+f_2+f_3)$$
Integrating throughout and using property $(1)$, we find that:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} (f_1+f_2+f_3)^2 \ dx = 0$$

which is a contradiction. Hence, a triple of such functions satisfying the given properties along with the assumption I've included above won't exist.

Comment: hm, thanks, but that assumption is too restrictive..

Comment: Yep, I just decided to put this out there in case someone else could use it to find a more complete solution